# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in my snake sort algorithm

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Trying to sort the following 4x4 matrix using snake sort in c:

13 16 12 8

5 9 10 1

3 11 2 4

7 6 15 14

When I run my code however I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Never seen this before. I'm not sure where I am try to access memory I shouldn't be in this code.

```
void EvenRowSort(int matrix[4][4], int i, int n){
    int j, temp=0;
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        if(matrix[i][j] > matrix[i][j+1]){
            temp = matrix[i][j+1];
            matrix[i][j+1] = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void OddRowSort(int matrix[][4], int i, int n){
    int j, temp=0;
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        if(matrix[i][j] < matrix[i][j+1]){
            temp = matrix[i][j+1];
            matrix[i][j+1] = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void ColSort(int matrix[][4], int j, int n){
    int temp, i = 0;
    for(i=0; i <n-1;j++){
        if(matrix[i][j] > matrix[i+1][j]){
            temp = matrix[i+1][j];
            matrix[i+1][j] = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void SnakeSort(int matrix[][4], int n){
    int m, i, j, k;
    //m=log(n)/log(2);
    m=3;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if((j % 2) == 0)
                EvenRowSort(matrix, j, n);
            else 
                OddRowSort(matrix, j, n);
        }
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
            ColSort(matrix, k, n);
    }

}

int main(void){
    FILE *inFile;
    inFile = fopen("input.txt","r");
    int n=4;
    int matrix[n][n];
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
            //printf("input number is: %d\n", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Input matrix is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    SnakeSort(matrix, n);
    printf("Output matrix is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get a sorted matrix like this:

1  2  3  4

8  7  6  5

9  10 11 12

16 15 14 13

Comment: Use a debugger to see where exacly you get a segmentation fault. You can even get a stack trace from the `core` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `void ColSort(int matrix[][4], int j, int n)`, you have problem with for loop. You don't increment `i` variable instead of you incremented `j` variable. It made out of bound on matrix.

So

```
for(i=0; i <n-1;j++){
```

should be replaced by:

```
for(i=0; i <n-1;i++){
```